# Como puedo convertir un Arreglo de tipo String que contiene Horas a uno de tipo Float?

Tags: java, android-studio, mysqli

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación en la que recupero una consulta de MySQL sobre horas y lo guardo en un arreglo de tipo String, este arreglo la quiero introducir en una gráfica pero la grafica requiere un arreglo de tipo float.

El arreglo que me recupera la consulta es algo como esto:

Hour = {"10:20:15","10:45:50"};

Habrá la posibilidad de convertir este arreglo a uno de tipo float o double?
He intentado hacer lo siguiente y para ser honesto soy nuevo en la programacion.

```
       float[] Hora = new float[Hour.size()];
       for (int h = 0; h< Hour.size();h++ ){
           Hora[h] = Float.parseFloat(Hour.get(h));
       }
```

O si lo puedo resolver desde esta parte:

```
ArrayList<String> Hour = new ArrayList<>();


JsonObjectRequest InformDay = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response.length()>0) {
                            try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("registro");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject objeto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String hora = objeto.optString("Hora");
                                        Hour.add(hora);
                                    }
                                } catch(JSONException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No fue posible obtener el registro",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    },
                            new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){
                    }
                    }
        );
        rq.add(InformDay);
    }
```

Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Un float (o double, es lo mismo en este caso) es un número de coma flotante, es decir, un decimal. Un decimal normalito, de los que escribimos toda la vida... con una única coma. Veo complicado convertir un string con dos puntos dobles en un float. Voy a necesitar que seas mucho más específico aquí, qué número exacto necesitas conseguir para representar esas horas? Por ejemplo, para la `10:20:15` necesitas `102015`?? Porque obviamente el parser de float no va a entender tantos símbolos `:`, pero si se lo das "limpio", si (por ejemplo usando `replace(":", "")` en el string...)

Comment: Todo depende de qué quieres conseguir: si tienes el valor `"10:30:00"`, ¿quieres obtener `10.5`?

Comment: Si te sirve un entero largo puede usar una [*marca de tiempo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

Comment: Me gustaría obtener por ejemplo un 10.2015 o 10.20 de un 10:20:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes reemplazar el primer ":" por "." y los siguientes ":" eliminarlos, después de esto puedes realizar la conversión a float:

```
 String[] Hour = {"10:20:15","10:45:50"};
  
  float[] Hora = new float[Hour.length]; 

  for (int i = 0; i< Hour.length;i++ ){
       //System.out.println(Hour[i]);
       //Reemplaza el primer ":" por "." y  los siguientes ":" los elimina.
       String result = Hour[i].replaceFirst(":", ".").replaceFirst(":", ""); 
       //Convierte valores a float del array Hour y los agrega a array Hora.
       Hora[i] = Float.parseFloat(result);           
   }
```

Al final tendrías un arreglo `Hora` de valores tipo `Float` conteniendo los siguientes valores:

```
10.2015
10.455
```

Comment: Gracias! me ayudó bastante, no sabía como resolver esa cuestión.